# Eligibility for free overnight stay since Turkish Airlines cancelled return flight and rebooked me the next day

Tags: layovers, turkey, turkish-airlines

In order to travel in December at reasonable costs I booked my multi-stop flights as follows:

> All flights booked under same ticket number and same Airline (Turkish Airlines)

1. `AMS` - `IST` - `BOM`
2. `BOM` - `IST` - `BRE`

Return flight (`BOM` to `BRE`) was booked for 27. December 2019. However I just got an email from Turkish Airlines that the flight has changed.

[image: Flight Changes]

As observed, the flight is now scheduled to fly off from 28. December 2019. I arrive in `IST` on the 27th December and since the flight is scheduled the next day do I get an overnight stay? I am flying from and back to Europe and wanted to know if I have some passenger rights here?

I now unfortunately have to apply for an `e-visa` and wish to know if in worst-case scenarios have to book an accomodation for one night because of the rescheduling or will the Airlines handle it for me?

Comment: When is the first leg (AMS-BOM)?

Comment: And did you ask for rebook after Turkish Airlines cancelled return flight?

Comment: @NRandhawa Last Week November 2019. I am trying to contact the customer service hotline and entered my TK Frequent Flyer Number and checked the cancelled flight as well as the rebooked flight but the service says the flight information is not available. I might have to send an email or contact the local TK office at the airport.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will be eligible for a free hotel, and transportation to the hotel.

Turkish airlines offers this for all connections that are longer than 12 hours (for economy class, 9 hours for business class) where a shorter option is not available - which in this case it is not.

You can find details of this service on the [Turkish Airlines website](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-us/flights/hotel-service/index.html).  When you arrive in Istanbul simply go to the Hotel Desk (which is in the land-side arrivals area) and they will book the hotel and provide transportation there.

As you've stated, you will need to obtain visa in order to make use of this service.